# Discord.net 401 Unauthorized Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, console, discord.net

I am trying to upgrade my bot from Discord.net 2.4.0 to 3.4.0. Now all actions from my bot will return an 401 Unauthorized exception.

This how I had it setup.

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x => x
                    .SetBasePath(GetBasePath())
                    .Build())
                .ConfigureLogging(x => x
                    .AddConsole()
                    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug))
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
                    var serverversion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => { options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverversion); }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
                    services.AddSingleton<LavaNode>();
                    services.AddSingleton<LavaConfig>();
                    services.AddSingleton<AudioService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<SteamService>();
                    services.AddHostedService<CommandHandler>();
                    services.AddLavaNode(x =>
                    {
                        x.SelfDeaf = false;
                        x.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Debug;
                    });
                })
                .ConfigureDiscordHost((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.SocketConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig
                    {
                        LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
                        AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
                        MessageCacheSize = 200,
                        GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All,
                    };
                    config.Token = context.Configuration["Token"];
                })
                .UseCommandService((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.CaseSensitiveCommands = false;
                    config.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug;
                    config.DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Sync;
                })
            .UseConsoleLifetime();

        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

This is what I get on my console

```
info: Discord.Addons.Hosting.DiscordHostedService[0]
      Discord.NET hosted service is starting
info: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Discord: Discord.Net v3.4.0 (API v9)
dbug: Discord.Addons.Hosting.CommandServiceRegistrationHost[0]
      Registered logger for CommandService
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Diego\source\repos\fernandesdiego\Bota\Bota\bin\Debug\net5.0
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
info: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: Connecting
dbug: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Rest: GET gateway: 252,26 ms
warn: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
warn: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
info: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: Connected
dbug: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: Connected to Servidor de Teste
info: Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
      Gateway: Ready


###### trying to execute the /ping command #######


fail: Discord.Commands.CommandService[0]
      Command:
      Discord.Commands.CommandException: Error occurred executing "ping" for ?Diego Fernandes?#3566 in Servidor de Teste/geral.
       ---> Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 401: 401: Unauthorized
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync(String method, String endpoint, RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendJsonAsync[TResponse](String method, String endpoint, Object payload, BucketId bucketId, ClientBucketType clientBucket, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.CreateMessageAsync(UInt64 channelId, CreateMessageParams args, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.Rest.ChannelHelper.SendMessageAsync(IMessageChannel channel, BaseDiscordClient client, String text, Boolean isTTS, Embed embed, AllowedMentions allowedMentions, MessageReference messageReference, MessageComponent components, ISticker[] stickers, RequestOptions options, Embed[] embeds, MessageFlags flags)
         at Bota.Modules.General.PingAsync() in C:\Users\Diego\source\repos\fernandesdiego\Bota\Bota\Modules\General.cs:line 32
         at Discord.Commands.ModuleClassBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<BuildCommand>g__ExecuteCallback|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Discord.Commands.CommandInfo.ExecuteInternalAsync(ICommandContext context, Object[] args, IServiceProvider services)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I call `await _service.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _provider)` on my `MessageReceived` event, and my command is like this:

```
public class General : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    ///...
    [Command("ping")]
    [RequireBotPermission(ChannelPermission.SendMessages)]
    public async Task PingAsync()
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Pong!");
        //ReplyAsync("Pong"); produces the same error //
    }
  ///...
}
```

I double checked my Token and I can see my bot online. I get the data from discord but can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the [Discord.Addons.Hosting](https://github.com/Hawxy/Discord.Addons.Hosting) package. It was broken somehow, even after cleaning and rebuilding my app. Anyway, I reinstalled and it worked.