# Discord.NET DiscordRestClient 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net v3.5.0.

I have an OAuth2 Access Token and I'm trying to use a `DiscordRestClient` to get the user's guilds, but I'm getting back 401 Unauthorized.

```cs
DiscordRestClient discordClient = new();
await discordClient.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bearer, accessToken);
IReadOnlyCollection<IGuild> restGuilds = await discordClient.GetGuildsAsync();
```

Stepping over `await discordClient.GetGuildsAsync()` throws the exception.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'iPxGWxw_tZW73Ya4zYXPehZr3w_Wdcs9uXYuEaUkslY'.
      Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 401: 401: Unauthorized
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync(String method, String endpoint, RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendAsync[TResponse](String method, String endpoint, BucketId bucketId, ClientBucketType clientBucket, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.GetGuildAsync(UInt64 guildId, Boolean withCounts, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.Rest.ClientHelper.GetGuildsAsync(BaseDiscordClient client, Boolean withCounts, RequestOptions options)
```

I can successfully use a regular `HttpClient` though, so I can confirm the Access Token is valid.

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
JsonArray? myGuilds = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<JsonArray>("https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/guilds");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With this sort of problem I usually use the Fiddler proxy and examine the differences between the two requests

Comment: According to this, one of the packages might've not installed properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398301/discord-net-401-unauthorized-exception?rq=1

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I do not have this package installed

Comment: Ah, was worth a shot - it looked it was a request to the same area.

Comment: Is this a bot you are coding?

Comment: @daveBM No, I am using an OAuth token to login on behalf of an actual user.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialize `DiscordRestClient` proberly.

```
DiscordRestClient discordClient = new();
```

Initializes a new [DiscordRestClient](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.Rest.DiscordRestClient.html) with the provided configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are defining the correct "scope" when you send the initial OAuth2 request. For example, since you're trying to get guilds there, your scope should also contain "guilds".

Example:

```cs
            var args = new Dictionary<string, string?>
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", CLIENT_ID_HERE ?? "" },
                { "scope", "identify guilds email" }, // make sure you add all the permissions you need here
                { "state", SESSION_ID_HERE ?? "" },
                { "redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI_HERE ?? "" }
            };

            string url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString($"https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize", args);
            controller.Redirect(url);
```